# ng2-facebook-sdk login is not working

Tags: angular, facebook-sdk-4.0

I was just trying to make a Facebook login. But the following error is showing. I am attaching the screenshot of the error. both in safari and chrome.
In chrome [Chrome Login Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvMIb.png)

My Facebook login component is like this

```
export class FacebookLoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private fb: FacebookService) {
        const initParams: InitParams = {
            appId: Config.facebook_api_id,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.8'
        };

        this.fb.init(initParams);
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    loginWithFacebook(): void {
        this.fb.login({scope: 'email, public_profile'})
            .then(
                (response: LoginResponse) => {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            )
           .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));

    }
}
```

[Github Issue link](https://github.com/zyra/ng2-facebook-sdk/issues/70)

Need help.TIA